# Visual Studio 2010 debugger not doing anything for WCF project

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, debugging, service

I have a WCF web service (using .NET 3.5) that I am trying to debug.  However, whenever I set any breakpoints in the program, they are never hit when running in debug mode.  Also, no exceptions are caught by Visual Studio--normally, when an uncaught exception is thrown while debugging, Visual Studio will show the exception being thrown and take you to the line of code where the exception was thrown.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: Are the symbols loaded? PDB files.....

Comment: When debugging are your break points red dots or red rings with a empty center?

Comment: I don't see anything in the Output window mentioning PDB files, or should I look elsewhere for that info?

Comment: Scott: They are red dots, not the empty-center rings, so Visual Studio seems to be claiming they're hittable--but they never are.

Comment: Try inserting the line `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();` inside your WCF service, then compile.  Run it.  If that doesn't launch the debugger, you must be hitting another instance of the service... or something.

Comment: ...interesting.  Yoda's suggestion opens up a new instance of VS2010 to debug it and that seems to work okay.  Why would this not work in the instance of Visual Studio that I'm running the program from, though?

Comment: @DashRantic: I couldn't say.  What that function does is invoke the global windows debugger.  Anyway.  So now we know that you are indeed hitting that code and able to debug it.  So now the question is what's up with your debugger.  Were you able to debug it before and suddenly can't anymore?

Comment: @DashRantic:  How do you launch your debugger?  Hit F5?  Is your WCF service hosted on IIS or the VS Dev Server?

Comment: Yes, I just hit F5 to debug.  I had a prior test version (in a different solution) of this project that I could debug, then when I added the project to the release solution I started having this issue.

Comment: yodaj007, if you want to place an answer regarding the use of System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();, I'll accept it--I haven't found any other solution so far and have been using that technique.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps trying to remotely debug the service? In that case you need to run the VS Remote Debugger on the remote computer as well.

Also you should set the Service Debug Behavior in your code to get exception details, like this:

```
ServiceHost MyServiceHost = new ServiceHost(myService, myBaseAddress);

#if CONFIG = "Debug"
//set Service Debug Behavior (for security should not be enabled during deployment)
Description.ServiceDebugBehavior sdb = MyServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<Description.ServiceDebugBehavior>();
if (sdb == null) {
sdb = new Description.ServiceDebugBehavior();
MyServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(sdb);
}
sdb.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;
#endif

MyServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), new NetTcpBinding(), myBaseAddress);
MyServiceHost.Open();
```

Comment: I'm not trying to remotely debug--this is all local atm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very late with this answer, but maybe it will help someone else.  You can experience this problem when you are debugging a web service that uses the local IIS instead of the Visual Studio dev server.

In this case, you must attach to the running instance of IIS, not just hit "Run".  To do this, click on Debug=>Attach To Process.  Then, select the Process, "w3wp.exe".  Finally, select "Attach" and you should be all set.

[image]